# PHP include vs file_get_contents

Tags: php, include, file-get-contents

So I've been using file_get_contents to request a file via a plugin for Wordpress I distribute to other users.

Anyway originally what I was doing was checking to see if the user has 'allow_url_fopen' enabled and if so going straight for file_get_contents. If not, I then checked to see if the user has cURL enabled, and if so take that route. The code is below:

```
if ( ini_get( 'allow_url_fopen' ) == 1 ) {
    $content = file_get_contents( $file );
    return $content;      
}
elseif ( function_exists( 'curl_version' ) ) {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, riva_slider_pro_dir( true ) . $file );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );

    $content = curl_exec( $curl );
    curl_close( $curl );

    return $content;
}
```

However, here is the issue I've run into. A particular users host blocked the file_get_contents function from accessing files altogether, whilst leaving allow_url_fopen enabled. Nothing would work, relative paths, absolute paths, nothing. So I turned to another solution, and find out that this worked:

```
    ob_start();
    include $file;
    $content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
```

My question is, how reliable is this method? With this, I have been using a local path, such as 'admin/file.css', etc.

If I decide to replace the top code with this, what kind of hosting setup could stop it from working? Using this method doesn't provide a way for me to check if something has gone wrong.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? If the PHP instance running your code does not enable allow_url_fopen, then you should respect that, and not try to bypass it. If the operation of your code is impeded by this, then you should simply disable your code until the required configuration is set.

Comment: The plugin tries to get the contents of a CSS file. It then modifies it and creates a new single CSS file. The various CSS properties are set through an admin panel. Also, The files being accessed are all within the same directory as the plugin itself. The styling is applied to a jQuery slideshow. Without the styling, it won't function.

Comment: One should not try to fetch a file which is stored in the application tree via HTTP. It is available locally, so allow_url_fopen is irrelevant. By using HTTP to fetch the contents of the file, you are adding a large amount of overhead, and making the entire process error-prone.

Comment: This is what I was thinking, but for whatever reason I couldn't get file_get_contents to work with a local URL (on my MAMP localhost setup anyway). Does this function work with local urls?

Comment: I think the mistake you're making is to think in terms of "URLs". You are trying to open a file locally, so you should be referring to it by its location on the filesystem. For instance "css/foo.css".

Comment: Sorry I think it might have came across wrong in that last comment. I have tried using 'admin/file.css' which works for the include() function but not for file_get_contents().

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6490/discussion-between-frozenfire-and-matthew-ruddy)

Comment: A host that forbids `file_get_contents` should be abandoned. That's a silly restriction.

Answer (score 2):

Your `include` method will be much less reliable. Disabling `file_get_contents` is rare, while `allow_url_include` (which you're implicitly depending on) is off by default.

It's also incredibly insecure. If your web server is hacked and someone modifies one of the files that your plugin is loading to include PHP code in the output, everyone with your plugin installed will start running that code. That would be REALLY BAD.

Comment: Ok. Would you know any other ways I could go about it? Really stuck with this one particular user. His host replied to an email they sent him saying file_get_contents would work if I tried it locally. I'm not really sure what they mean as putting a local path into file_get_contents wouldn't work (on my offline setup anyway using MAMP on Mac).

Comment: I'd suggest trying the `curl` method before `file_get_contents`. If `curl` is enabled, it's pretty likely to work for downloading content. (Otherwise it'd be totally useless!)